# Twitter logins will give my email to websites?

Tags: twitter, openid

When I login with Twitter to websites, will they get my email address?

The authorization screen is not clear in this, Facebook instead says clearly that is giving my name and email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter API doesn't return the email address when you login using that, so no, they won't get the email address.

Comment: Good to know, I'll use Twitter login when possible, I don't want to give my email everywhere